# getting error "Expected false to be true"

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have function called sunset that copies the existing array sunsetColors by reference and then changes the first element to "blue". sunset should return the copy of the array.

```
function sunset(){
  let clone =sunsetColors;
clone.splice(0,0,"blue");
  return clone;
}
sunset()
```

Comment: well it is not a copy.... `console.log(sunsetColors, clone)`

Comment: what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value

Comment: @Divya just add it with destructuring as such `[ "blue", ...sunsetColors ]`

Comment: @darklightcode does that replace the first element with "blue"?

Comment: it is replacing the first element to "blue.

Comment: It will create a new array where "blue" is at position 0 and the rest of the elements will be added by the `...`(spread operator)

Comment: but i am getting "sunset should create a copy by reference and change the first element to blue" failure message

Comment: @darklightcode OP asked "and then changes the first element to 'blue'"

Comment: thats what this code do right ?
[ "blue", ...sunsetColors ] changing the first element to "blue"

Comment: @Divya it actually prepends "blue" to the array, as first element. When you say `change`, you mean `replace the first element` or `place at the beginning`?

Comment: My apologies, i may have misread , try this, `clone.splice(0,1,"blue");` , the second parameter of `.splice` will replace the item from position 0 in `clone`. If that doesn't help. Please provide us a sample of `sunsetColors` and the expected outcome.

Comment: i tried that already , but i am still getting
"sunset should create a copy by reference and change the first element to blue"
" sunset should not change the rest of the array"
"Expected false to be true."

Comment: @Divya where exactly are you getting that message from?

Comment: jasmine spec runner

Comment: If you have an array like `let arr = ['red', 'yellow']`, then you can copy it like `let clone = arr.slice()`. Then you can change the first element of the copy like `clone[0] = 'blue'`.

Comment: i just changed to this and it worked. 
```
function sunset() {
  sunsetColors[0] = "blue";
  return (clone = sunsetColors.slice());
}
sunset();
```
thank you all...

Answer (score 1):

try the following code for cloning

```
let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sunsetColors));
```

Here is a very good article for array cloning in Javascript.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-clone-an-array-in-javascript-1d3183468f6a/

Answer (score 0):

This does not copy the array.

`let clone =sunsetColors;`

At the end of that statement, clone and sunsetColors are both pointing to the same array.

To copy the array, try something such as

`let clone = [...sunsetColors];`

Or you could copy the array this way

`let clone = sunsetColors.slice();`